# Real time device share on Apple TV via AirPlay

Tags: streaming, screen-sharing

I see that there are apps that will broadcast certain things to an Apple TV via AirPlay, but is there a way to send a view of the screen in real time via this method?  I have seen iPhone 4S doing this, but the only apps I've seen for Android advertise that they broadcast media files as if they're being sent as opposed to streamed.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any apps that can do that, but (supposedly) any Android 4.2 device can do that with a wireless display adapter connected to an HDMI-enabled TV. I also found [this project by E.S.R.Labs](http://www.cnx-software.com/2012/07/04/android-transporter-enables-wifi-display-mirroring-similar-to-miracast-of-android-devices/), which they successfully get a Nexus S to mirror it's screen (albeit onto a Raspberry Pi). Mirroring functionality is also sometimes limited due to hardware requirements.

I also recently found that a developer was able to get Miracast working on Nexus 7 and 4 variants. Check it out [on XDA with videos](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2348991). Something cool to note with this project is that the mirroring capabilities are all software based; no need for additional hardware. Hopefully that will also lead to further development for mirroring on devices that don't already have the hardware inside of them.